# Supremum of the set of terms of the geometric series.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

Let $a \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $0<|a|<1$ and

$A=\{1+a+a^2+...+a^k+...+a^n|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Find the supremum of $A$ using the fundamental property of supremum:

$s=\sup A \Leftrightarrow s $ is an upper bound of $A$ and $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists x \in A$ such that $s-\epsilon<x$.

My thoughts are to take cases where $a$ is positive and negative and then take cases for the negative case where $n$ is an even number and odd.

My strategy is to find supremum $s$ of $A$ and then prove that any element of $A$ smaller than $s$ cannot be a supremum of $A$ contradicting the Archimedean principle:

$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $n\epsilon>1$

I have a difficulty to find the supremum of $A$ and prove that indeed is the least upper bound.

I'm new to real analysis.

I would be very thankful if someone could help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT 1.

Use $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n a^k={1-a^{n+1}\over1-a}$ and show that $\displaystyle\sup A={1\over1-a}$ if $a\ge0$. In other words, you must prove that, for any $\epsilon>0$:
$$
{1\over1-a}-\epsilon\le{1-a^{n+1}\over1-a}\le{1\over1-a}
\quad\hbox{for some $n$}.
$$

HINT 2.

If $a<0$ prove that $\sup A=1$.

Comment: ..i have used that but stil i cannot find the supremum..if $a>0$ then i pressume that the supremum is $\frac{1}{1-a}$ but what if $a$ is negative..?..Also i have to prove that the element i will find is indeed asupremum using the property i mentioned

Comment: I edited a bit my answer, but I think now you can go on by yourself.

Comment: Hello @Aretino , I have a question. When $-1<\alpha<0$, how do we show that the least upper bound of the set is $1$ ?

Comment: @Evinda In that case $1$ is the maximum of $A$. Just consider the cases with odd and even $n$ to show all other elements are $\le1$.

Comment: Let $-1<\alpha<0 $. We set $\beta=-\alpha$.
$$$$
Then we have the following.

$$1+\dots+\alpha^n=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1+\beta^{n+1}}{1+\beta} &, \text{ if  n is even} \\ 
\frac{1-\beta^{n+1}}{1+\beta} &, \text{ if n is odd} 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Does it hold that the least upper bound is $ \frac{1}{1+\beta}$, if $n$ is odd, and $\frac{2}{1+\beta}$ if $n$ is even? Or am I doing something wrong? @Aretino

Comment: If $n$ is even, $\beta^{n+1}\le\beta$ so that $(1+\beta^{n+1})/(1+\beta)\le1$ and in particular it is $=1$ if $n=0$. If $n$ is odd, $(1+\beta^{n+1})/(1+\beta)<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$b_n
=\sum_{k=0}^n a^k
$
and
$b
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a^k
$.

Then
$b_n
=\dfrac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}
$
and
$b
=\dfrac{1}{1-a}
$.

Then
$b-b_n
=\dfrac{a^{n+1}}{1-a}
\to 0
$
as
$n \to \infty
$.

To show this:

If $a > 0$,
then
$a = \dfrac1{1+c}$
where
$c = \dfrac1{a}-1
\gt 0$.

Therefore,
by Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+c)^{m}
\ge 1+mc
\gt mc
=m(\dfrac1{a}-1)
$
so
$\dfrac{a^{n+1}}{1-a}
=\dfrac{1}{(1-a)(1+c)^{n+1}}
\lt \dfrac{1}{(1-a)(n+1)(\dfrac1{a}-1)}
= \dfrac{a}{(1-a)^2(n+1)}
\to 0
$.

If
$a < 0$
then
$|b-b_n|
=|\dfrac{a^{n+1}}{1-a}|
=\dfrac{|a^{n+1}|}{1+|a|}
=\dfrac{|a|^{n+1}}{1+|a|}
\to 0
$
the same as for
$a > 0$.

Comment: i have not been introduced your to the notion of limit..can you help me by just using the properties a mentioned?